# change div display when scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey guys i am trying to make transition when the scroll it pass the first div( that is with the class name "one") height it will resize it width to 20% and the second div ( with the class name "two") will take the remaining width of the "one" class. <== when this happened it will turn the "two" class to a display as a block rather than inline-block. the problem that i have right now is that when the ".one" class it got resize to 20% the ".two" class disappear same as the below class and when the ".two" class disappear when i scroll up it only resize the ".one" class div halfway . can anyone help me how to achieve this? here's my code and some image that i made of a transition that i want to make in case still confused of what i want to achieve. thanks for the help.

in here it shown from this image to the left shown display of the page before scroll and from the right image shown when the user scroll the page that will reduce the size of the div class ".
[image]

in this section of image from the left shown when the width of the div class ".one" is have width of 20% it will not resize it again and for the right image shown when the div class ".one" have width of 20% it will change the css of div class ".two" from inline block to display block and when it scroll it will show the third div.
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      height: 2000px;
    }

    .container {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      position: fixed;
    }

    .content-wrapper {
      width: 100vw;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .section {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .section label {
      font-size: 100px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    }

    .one {
      background-color: red;
      top: 0;
      z-index: -999;
    }

    .two {
      background-color: yellow;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="section one">
          <label>one</label>
        </div>
        <div class="section two">
          <label>two</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="revelation" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background-color: black;">
        <label>Tree</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() + 0,
        zeroSizeHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height(),
        newSize = 1400 * (1 - (winScrollTop / zeroSizeHeight));
        let box = document.querySelector('.one');
        let width = box.clientWidth;
        console.log(newSize)
        if(newSize > 331.13772455089827 ){
            $(".one").css({
                "width":newSize
            })
        }else if(newSize <= 331.13772455089827){
            $(".section").css({
                "display":"block"

            })
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, why do you change the second div to block when it expands - won't that force it to below the first div or have I misunderstood?